# Valgrind Error - Address 0x0 is not stack'd malloc'd or free'd

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I am trying to allocate memory based on the number of columns and rows that are declared in main line arguments. For example a.out 2 4 6 would mean run a.out with 2 players, 4 columns, 6 rows.

I am expecting memory to be allocated with the board_init function but valgrind returns:
 Invalid read size 1 at user_input_players(int, char**)
And that the heap has allocated 0, with 0 frees, and no leaks possible.

I am only familiar with new and delete commands. I'm not sure how to understand the error message.

```
// function declaration
int user_input_players(int choices, char** selection);
int user_input_columns(int choices, char** selection);
int user_input_rows(int choices, char** selection);
int board_init(int columns, int rows);


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 int column = 0, row = 0, player = 0;

 player = user_input_players(argc, argv);
 column = user_input_columns(argc, argv);
 row = user_input_rows(argc, argv);
 board_init(column, row);
 return 0;
}

int user_input_players(int choices, char** selection){
  int player_count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < choices; i++){
    selection[i];
  }
  while( !(*selection[1] == '1' || *selection[1] == '2')){
    cout << "Please enter number of players: " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> player_count;
   if(player_count == 1 || player_count == 2){
    return player_count;
   }
  player_count = *selection[1];
  return player_count;
 }
}

int user_input_columns(int choices, char** selection){
 int column_count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < choices; i++){
  selection[i];
  }
 column_count = atoi(selection[2]);
 if(column_count >= 4 && column_count <= 20){
  return column_count;
  }
 while( !(column_count >= 4 && column_count <= 20)){
  cout << "Please enter number of columns: " << endl;
  cin.clear();
  cin >> column_count;
   if(column_count >= 4 && column_count <= 20){
     return column_count;
    }
  }
}

int user_input_rows(int choices, char** selection){
 int row_count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < choices; i++){
   selection[i];
   }
 row_count = atoi(selection[3]);
 if(row_count >= 4 && row_count <= 20){
   return row_count;
  }
 while( !(row_count >= 4 && row_count <= 20)){
    cout << "Please enter number of rows: " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> row_count;
    if(row_count >= 4 && row_count <= 20){
      return row_count;
    }
  }
}

 void board_init(int columns, int rows){  // Valgrind shows no memory allocation because of error
  int** board = new int*[rows];
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   board[i] = new int[columns];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your functions are declared to return a value, but you failed to do so in many instances.  Are you reading your compiler errors and warnings?  The code as-is invokes undefined behavior due to this.  For example, `int board_init`, but where do you return an `int`?

Comment: int** board in board_init creates a local variable to that function. Not likely what you want to get

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand and I will fix those. However this is just a snippet, the code compiles and runs using g++ without any errors. I am trying to determine why my memory is not working.

Comment: `int** board = new int*[rows];`  -- As mentioned, this is a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use vector change your init_board function to use a 2d vector instead:

```
vector<vector<int> > vec( row , vector<int> (column));
```

This will prevent the memory leak that is happening. You should also consider doing this directly in main. Or if you want to keep your function the way that it is you should consider returning `int**` from your function and storing it to a `int**` variable in main so that you can delete it later. Currently you have a memory leak because you are never deleting the memory that you are allocating in `board_init`.

Comment: I cannot use vectors as this is a class assignment. 

Also, I'm sorry this was not clear, the error happens without board_init. I am expecting valgrind to return the allocated memory warning and that it has not been free'd because I have not deleted it yet.